# paypal subscription issue

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I want to know what does this means : " $10.00 USD for each 24 days "

I am using PayPal Subscription Payment, and I want to get $10 USD for 24 day. How can I set it using HTML Form Variables?

I have used the following code:

```
<input type="hidden" value="D" name="t3">
<input type="hidden" value="24" name="p3">
```

Am I correct, or how can I achieve the above mentioned thing (i.e., getting $10 USD for 24 days only)

Comment: You are not newbie here right?, Please try to format your question next time.

Comment: @Shakti Singh: oops, I forgot in hurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
<input type="hidden" name="srt" value="24">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="10.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="D">
```

and it will read as:

```
$10.00 USD for each day, for 24 installments
```

Answer (score 1):

a3-->Regular subscription price;

t3--->Regular subscription units of duration. Allowable values:
     D – for days; allowable range for p3 is 1 to 90
         W – for weeks; allowable range for p3 is 1 to 52
         M – for months; allowable range for p3 is 1 to 24
         Y – for years; allowable range for p3 is 1 to 5

p3--->Subscription duration. Specify an integer value in the allowable range for the units of duration that you specify with t3.

Please read the above and change accordingly
<input type="hidden" value="D" name="t3">

Comment: I want to get $10 USD for 24 day, but I think that code that I have written is wrong or am I right?

Comment: <input type="hidden" value="D" name="t3">
<input type="hidden" value="24" name="p3">

Comment: I don't understand, whether above code will get amount only for 24 days only, or at regular interval of 24 days till subscription is cancelled?

Comment: @I-M-JM: First you were wrong,what you have written now is correct.Its for regular interval for 24 days till subscription is cancelled.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong at first go. Now that I have corrected, can you please guide me

Comment: Please read the paypal standard methode ,It will be better for you.

Comment: I have read it, but I don't understand it. So, have asked for help.

Comment: src-->Recurring payments. Subscription payments recur unless subscribers cancel their subscriptions.    
  *0 – subscription payments do not recur  *1 – subscription payments recur

          0 – subscription payments do not recur
          1 – subscription payments recur
 sra-->Reattempt on failure. If a recurring payment fails, @I-M-JM: PayPal attempts to collect the payment two more times before canceling the subscription.
          0 – do not reattempt failed recurring payments
          1 – reattempt failed recurring payments before canceling

Answer (score 0):

You're not able to limit the length of a subscription.

You can take payments every day using the following

```
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="D" />
```

This would give you payments being taken every day, the code in the previous answer will take payment every 24 days.

You need to use the above code and either, using Paypal's API, cancel the subscription, OR cancel it manually.

Comment: can you explain how can I cancel subscription using PayPal API?

Comment: I had a read through this which describes how to cancel subscriptions, however I think that it may be for the client and not the merchant receiving the subscription. Sorry, I don't think it's possible. Reference URL: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECRecurringPayments